# java 7 not installing because IP not found

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jdk

Tried installing netbeans and eclipse but both give the following errors (is this caused because the server is down and will be restored soon? I've not been able to use apt-get to install the missing packages either. Also tried http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html but it says that `ls`, `mkdir` etc are missing when it is not actually missing):

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main icedtea-netx-common all 1.2-2ubuntu1.3   
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80] Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main icedtea-netx-common all 1.2-2ubuntu1.3   
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80] 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main icedtea-netx
i386 1.2-2ubuntu1.3   
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80] 
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icedtea-web/icedtea-netx-common_1.2-2ubuntu1.3_all.deb
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80] Failed to fetch
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icedtea-web/icedtea-netx_1.2-2ubuntu1.3_i386.deb
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80] 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had downloaded the RPM, which turned out to be incompatible with Ubuntu. So I downloaded the tar file and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/148011) helped me install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the repository mirror. You can find a good guide for that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from).

If the problem still persists edit your original question to include that you have tried to change the mirror.

[If your interested you could also take a look at my answer about managing Java JDK in Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281425/how-can-i-remove-my-current-jdk-and-install-default-jdk/281433#281433)